# identify callback of which wcf request is current event handler

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, silverlight

Say I've this code:

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    client c = new client();
    c.fooAsyncCompleted+=h;
    c.fooAsync(i);
}
```

Where client class is generated from wcf service reference. Now in function `h` i need to know of which call of `c.fooAsync` result is currently being processed? Is there a way do do such thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the normal WCF proxy classes generated by Visual Studio you should have a method overload that takes a `UserState` argument.

```
c.fooAsync(i, i);
```

In your completed handler you can retrieve that argument via the `EventArgs`.

```
h(object sender, fooAsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var x = e.UserState;
}
```

With that information you will know to which call the callback belongs.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the source of the handled event from the first paramter of the handler, `object sender`

Assuming your handler looks like (generically)

```
void handler(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

You can have your `client` object through simple casting

```
var source = (client)sender;
```

How exactly you in turn identify it, is up to you (it depends on the class structure ... Since it needs to be identified, a unique "id" property would do).